# OneLogin OIDC - Spring Security Integration Failure

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, onelogin

I were following the sample provided in OneLogin Developer Portal - https://developers.onelogin.com/quickstart/authentication/java-spring. I did everything described in the article. But on running the application, authentication happens; I were taken to OneLogin page and I enters the credentials. But on redirection, I get following error.

[image: error-page]

"http://localhost:8081/login" is the redirect url configured in admin portal. And it is the default url which is been passed in the first request.

https://kore-wireless-dev.onelogin.com/oidc/2/auth?client_id=<?>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/login&response_type=code&scope=openid profile email&state=UY6Tam

In the [sample code](https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-java/tree/master/spring-boot-app), the endpoint is not implemented. But I don't think application developer needs to implement that endpoint.

I tried Github SSO. Where we can specify different redirect urls in app configuration (spring-security-url) and github sso configuration (app-url). And after authentication github will redirect to spring-security-url. And then that endpoint will redirect to app-url.

Is Spring Security OAuth2 is not compatible with OneLogin? Or what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faced the same issue. In my case, we had to modify the Authentication Method of the Token Endpoint in OneLogin oidc application. When it was set to Basic, it was throwing the Unauthorised error. Probably, the sample application invokes the OIDC token endpoint with credentials (clientID and clientSecret) in the payload request (POST Auth Method) rather than in request header(Basic Authentication method). Sharing the screenshot of the same here.
[image: OneLogin OIDC Auth Method]